# Saving images in different folders using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, webcam

I've been trying to save images from my webcam in different folders but it doesnt work. what im trying to achieve is im trying to save 5 images per folder from my webcam but it doesnot work. Can somebody please help? Thanks
P.S here is my code

```
def createFolder(directory):
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
    except OSError:
        print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)

import os 
import cv2 
import time 

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
counter = 0
while(video_capture.isOpened()):
    location = f'D:/DATA_SCIENCE/anand_fabrics/{counter}'
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(location , f"frame{counter}.jpg"), frame)
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        createFolder(f'D:/DATA_SCIENCE/anand_fabrics/{counter}')
    counter = counter + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying you switch folder every 5 images, yet you change the path every single image:

```
while(video_capture.isOpened()):
    location = f'D:/DATA_SCIENCE/anand_fabrics/{counter}'
    ...
    counter = counter + 1
```

So basically you are trying to write to a non-existing path.

Try this:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
counter = 0
while(video_capture.isOpened()):
    if counter % 5 == 0:
        location = f'D:/DATA_SCIENCE/anand_fabrics/{counter}'
        createFolder(loaction)
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(location , f"frame{counter}.jpg"), frame)
    counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Great! See the update. If you like it please share, like & subscribe :P